# Uploading images to Google platform

Tags: google-app-engine, upload, google-cloud-storage

I am writing an Android application that allows users to upload and share photos. The server is based on Google App Engine. App Engine's datastore does not allow to save file, so currently I just have URLs saved. Looking for a way to store files I read about Google Cloud Storage. My question is - if I'm looking for a host for user uploaded files, is Google Cloud Storage what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Google Cloud Storage is the way forward. There is also the BlobStore API on App Engine that allows you to store large amounts of information but the road map seems to be clear i.e. use Google Cloud Storage moving forward.

The reason for going with GCS will also be influenced that eventually you might want various tools or utilities that people have written that work directly with GCS. With Blobstore API, you will need to write those utilities yourself or rely on Admin console's support for taking backup,etc - which is not really much.

In summary, go with GCS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats what you want. Says the same if you read the docs about google cloud storage.